# Google API invoice exceptional increasing

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Am using Google APIs(distance-matrix, places-details, and geo-coding)
and I always received an invoice by **$12000/month**
but suddenly the invoice increased to **$60000** in one day
Can Anyone explain whats the error and how I can contact google support??

[image]

Comment: You can contact Google Maps support team via developer console: `https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/support?project=[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]`

Comment: To add to xomena's answer, you can find the documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support and for premium plan customers please see https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support

Comment: To avoid getting such unexpected high bills going forward please look into securing your API keys with appropriate [application restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey) and setting [daily quota limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_cap) on the Maps APIs.